# Writing an Int value to a server is converting it to -1 in socket programming C

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, client-server

Hi im an trying to write an int from my client side to my server. My write on the client side is set up like this:

```
/* Writes an int to the server socket. */
void write_server_int(int sockfd, int msg)
{
    printf("\n[DEBUG] THIS IS the Message: %d", msg);
    printf("\n[DEBUG] THIS IS size of the Message: %lu", sizeof(msg));


    int n = write(sockfd, &msg, sizeof(msg));
    printf("\n[DEBUG] THIS IS N: %d", n);
    if (n < 0)
        error("ERROR writing int to server socket");

    printf("[DEBUG] Wrote int to server: %d\n", msg);
}
```

My receive on my server side is set up like this:

```
/* Reads an int from a client socket. */
int recv_int(int cli_sockfd)
{
    int msg = 0;
    int n = read(cli_sockfd, &msg, sizeof(msg));

    if (n < 0 || n != sizeof(int)) /* Not what we were expecting. Client likely disconnected. */
        return -1;

    printf("[DEBUG] Received int: %d\n", msg);

    return msg;
}
```

I am calling my functions from here:

```
while(1) {
        option = menu_screen(sockfd); // Get Menu Screen and Clients Choosen Option
        printf("[DEBUG] User selection menu option: %d\n", option);

        while (option == 1){ // Gameplay Option
            draw_board(board);
            recv_msg(sockfd, msg);
            if (!strcmp(msg, "TRN")) { /* Take a turn. */
                int choice = take_turn_member(sockfd);
                write_server_int(sockfd, choice);
            }
            if (!strcmp(msg, "COX")){
                int coordinates_x = take_turn_coord_x();
                printf("\n[DEBUG] Coordinates X is: %d", coordinates_x);
                write_server_int(sockfd, coordinates_x);
                printf("\n\nMADE IT HERE");
            }
            if (!strcmp(msg, "COY")){
                int coordinates_y = take_turn_coord_y();
                printf("\n[DEBUG] Coordinates Y is: %d", coordinates_y);
                write_server_int(sockfd, coordinates_y);
                printf("\n\nMADE IT HERE");
            }
}
```

My code works perfectly up until it reaches the                  `write_server_int(sockfd, coordinates_x);` here from the console output shows that the int being passed into the `write_server_int()` is being pushed to the server as -1.

```
[DEBUG] Received message: COX
Enter Row Tile Coordinates A-I : A

[DEBUG] Coordinates X is: 0
THIS IS the Message: 0
THIS IS size of the Message: 4
THIS IS N: -1
Either the server shut down or the other player disconnected.
Game over.
```

Can someone explain to me what is happening and how to fix it please?

Comment: Try using `strerror(errno)` to get a printable message about the error from `write`.

Comment: Also, please change your habit of using leading newline when calling `printf`. That will flush the *previous* line to the console, but leave your current output in the buffer. Use *trailing* newline instead, where you always *end* your output with a newline.

Comment: The value being written is not being "converted to -1". That -1 is the result of the `write` call, which is telling you the write *failed*.

Comment: Im getting 'Bad File Descriptor' would there be a possible reason for this?

Comment: "*possible reason*" Either the socket got closed or the variable's value was overwritten, either  explicitly or by messing up the programs memory management.

Answer (score 0):

> here from the console output shows that the int being passed into the write_server_int() is being pushed to the server as -1.

No, your Output says, that the result of `write()` is `-1`:

> ```
> int n = write(sockfd, &msg, sizeof(msg));
> printf("\n[DEBUG] THIS IS N: %d", n);
>
> [DEBUG] Coordinates X is: 0
> THIS IS the Message: 0
> THIS IS size of the Message: 4
> THIS IS N: -1 <------------------------ mind the 'N'
> ```

Comment: Can you see a reason why the write() is -1?  I understand it failed to write but why?

Comment: Some Programmer Dude told you what to do in the first comment to your question already.